# Debian 12 Home User App Launcher Location

Tags: linux, debian, kde

I've installed Debian 12 x64 **KDE** plasma desktop on Windows 10 host via VMWarePlayer (non-commercial). I have coded quite a few Bash routines that expand package tarballs (to /opt), and copy the *.desktop app launcher to,

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

or

```
/home/user/.local/share/applications
```

Debian 12 doesn't have this directory. My question is, where does Debian 12 place app-launcher *.desktop files to, for the home user (~/. or /home/user/.), that will show in the (new) start menu?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, if this directory doesn't exist after installing Debian 12, merely create this directory,

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/applications
```

Application launchers place in this directory will appear on the start menu.